# how to display menu from date in highchart

Tags: php, highcharts

i have problem with highchart,i want to display menu from-to date like this:
[image]

so here my code:

```js
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#project').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            margin: 75,
            options3d: {
                enabled: false,
                alpha: 10,
                beta: 25,
                depth: 70
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'CHART',
            style: {
                    fontSize: '18px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        },
        rangeSelector: {
            selected:2
                  
                },
        subtitle: {
           text: 'Project',
           style: {
                    fontSize: '15px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                depth: 25
            }
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories:  <?php echo json_encode($project);?>
        },
        exporting: { 
            enabled: false 
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Total'
            },
        },
        tooltip: {
             formatter: function() {
                 return 'The value for <b>' + this.x + '</b> is <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,0) + '</b>, in '+ this.series.name;
             }
          },
        series: [{
            name: 'Report Data',
            data: <?php echo json_encode($value);?>,
            shadow : true,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: '#045396',
                align: 'center',
                formatter: function() {
                     return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0);
                }, // one decimal
                y: 0, // 10 pixels down from the top
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        }]
    });
});
</script>
```

but actually i can't configure to display menu from date highchart.

how to configure highchart to display menu from date in highchart?

Comment: refer this : http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/range-selector

Answer (score 0):

Here - look at [this example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BWEm5). I am not sure if it is exactly what you are looking for but the range selector is there.

```js
$(function() {

    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function(data) {
        // Create the chart
        window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container'
            },

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1,
                inputDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d'
            },

            title: {
                text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'AAPL',
                data: data,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }}]

        }, function(chart) {

            // apply the date pickers
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('input.highcharts-range-selector', $('#' + chart.options.chart.renderTo)).datepicker()
            }, 0)
        });
    });


    // Set the datepicker's date format
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        onSelect: function(dateText) {
            this.onchange();
            this.onblur();
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 600px"></div>
```

Comment: You use a regular chart in your code, use a stockchart $('#container').highcharts('stockChart', ...) instead of $('#container').highcharts(...)